# Вывод слов разделенных символами с помощью Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть текст и мне необходимо выделить и записать слова, разделённые символами «_.,;:\n\t!?».  Я знаю, что это можно сделать с помощью Regex, но не могу предположить, как должен выглядеть подобный паттерн? Кто нибудь может помочь мне с этим на С#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего это сделать, используя метод [String.Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_). В примере ниже я добавил в список разделителей отсутствующие в тексте вопроса пробел и `\r`:

```
string text =
@"Зима!.. Крестьянин, торжествуя,
На дровнях обновляет путь;
Его лошадка, снег почуя,
Плетётся рысью как-нибудь";

var separators = new char[] { ' ', '_', '.', ',', ';', ':', '\r', '\n', '\t', '!', '?' };
string[] words = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
foreach (string word in words)
    Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Выдача:

```
Зима
Крестьянин
торжествуя
На
дровнях
обновляет
путь
Его
лошадка
снег
почуя
Плетётся
рысью
как-нибудь
```

Если всё же требуется использовать регулярное выражение:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"[^ _.,;:\r\n\t!?]+"))
    Console.WriteLine(match);
```

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding` вот это вот не нужно делать. Зачем?

Comment: @aepot Потому что без этой строки у меня на выходе будут видны только знаки вопроса (code page 437).

Comment: По умолчанию для русского CP 866 у всех стоит, а не UTF-8. Другими словами, не стоит это добавлять во все свои ответы, чтобы не сбивать никого с толку.

Comment: Можно кстати короче записать `text.Split("_.,;:\r\n\t!?".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`, но это как больше нравится, просто опция.

Comment: @aepot Если на Вашем компьютере по умолчанию используется кодовая страница 866, это совсем не означает, что так у всех. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp

Comment: Тем не менее, у кого русский в консоли не работает, прекрасно знают, что с этим делать. Мы же на русскоязычном ресурсе находимся, верно? А потом, от этого UTF-8 могут начаться проблемы, например если человек учит работу с процессами, запускает дочерний процесс типа `cmd.exe` и видит абракадабру. Здесь тысячи ответов про консоль, и ваш такой первый. Но вам конечно виднее.

Comment: @aepot // прекрасно знают, что с этим делать // И что именно Вы предлагаете делать вместо установки кодовой страницы?

Comment: Ничего не делать, просто не публикуйте эту строчку в ответах. Это не наезд, а совет.